# Kibana showing only a limited number of data - ELK Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I parsed an apache access log file using logstash and it parsed all the logs successfully as seen in the command prompt window. But when I open up Kibana it only shows 8 of it. Why doesn't it show all of the parsed logs?

### Updated:

I started all over again reinstalling elasticsearch-4.2.0, logstash-2.0.0 and Kibana 4. the name of my log file is `http_access_2015-03-06_log` and it is being parsed and showing in elasticsearch-kopf but not showing any of the logs on Kibana.

kopf
[image]

> command prompt output: *updated*

[image]

> .conf file : *updated*

```
   input {
  file {
    path => "G:/MIT/level_03/Project/logstash-2.0.0/bin/tmp/*_log"
    #sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  #grok {
  #  match => ["path", "G:/logstash-1.5.0/bin/tmp/(?<project>[^/_logs]+)/"]
  #}
  if [path] =~ "access" {
    mutate { replace => { type => "apache_access" } }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
  } else if [path] =~ "error" {
    mutate { replace => { type => "apache_error" } }
  } else {
    mutate { replace => { type => "random_logs" } }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
   # action => "index"
    hosts => "localhost" 
   # index => "test"
}
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

These are some logs parsed but not being shown on Kibana

> 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2015:10:26:31 +0530] "GET /carbon/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
>   127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2015:10:26:31 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux
>   x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111
>   Safari/537.36"
>   127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2015:10:26:32 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 3398 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
>   Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
>   127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2015:10:26:32 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/css/global.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5309
>   "https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
>   Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
>   127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2015:10:26:32 +0530] "GET /carbon/styles/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1361
>   "https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
>   Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
>   127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2015:10:26:32 +0530] "GET /carbon/dialog/css/dialog.css HTTP/1.1" 200 556
>   "https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
>   Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"

Kibana Discover Tab : *updated*
[image]

kibana.yml

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This controls which port to use.
# server.port: 5601

# The host to bind the server to.
# server.host: "0.0.0.0"

# The Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
# elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"

# preserve_elasticsearch_host true will send the hostname specified in `elasticsearch`. If you set it to false,
# then the host you use to connect to *this* Kibana instance will be sent.
# elasticsearch.preserveHost: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations
# and dashboards. It will create a new index if it doesn't already exist.
# kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
# kibana.defaultAppId: "discover"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic auth, this is the user credentials
# used by the Kibana server to perform maintenance on the kibana_index at startup. Your Kibana
# users will still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch (which is proxied through
# the Kibana server)
# elasticsearch.username: user
# elasticsearch.password: pass

# SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana Server to the browser (PEM formatted)
# server.ssl.cert: /path/to/your/server.crt
# server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# Optional setting to validate that your Elasticsearch backend uses the same key files (PEM formatted)
# elasticsearch.ssl.cert: /path/to/your/client.crt
# elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# If you need to provide a CA certificate for your Elasticsearch instance, put
# the path of the pem file here.
# elasticsearch.ssl.ca: /path/to/your/CA.pem

# Set to false to have a complete disregard for the validity of the SSL
# certificate.
# elasticsearch.ssl.verify: true

# Time in milliseconds to wait for elasticsearch to respond to pings, defaults to
# request_timeout setting
# elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or elasticsearch.
# This must be > 0
# elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 300000

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards.
# Set to 0 to disable.
# elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 0

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying
# elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Set the path to where you would like the process id file to be created.
# pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# If you would like to send the log output to a file you can set the path below.
# logging.dest: stdout

# Set this to true to suppress all logging output.
# logging.silent: false

# Set this to true to suppress all logging output except for error messages.
# logging.quiet: false

# Set this to true to log all events, including system usage information and all requests.
# logging.verbose
```

> p.s. Kiabna Discover tab shows all the data for "_all"

Comment: Have you tried setting `All time` in the top right corner of your Kibana web interface? In your screenshot it is `Last 30 minutes`.

Comment: Yes I did to today, week and month as well. Still this is all it shows.

Comment: Okay, could you please try to delete your index in the Settings tab, restart Kibana and elasticsearch and recreate your index afterwards?

Comment: I deleted the index from Settings tab in Kibana, restarted Kibana and elasticsearch and recreated the index in Kibana and now no data at all is shown in Kibana Discover tab. Totally lost.

Comment: Okay, you set the index in your output (`index => "test"`). Have you specified this index name (`test`) in the settings tab of Kibana? Please double check that. Apart from that, your output settings are not necessary. A blank elasticsearch output (`elasticsearch { }`) should work and give you an index like this: `"logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"`. Keep in mind that you need to configure Kibana correspondingly.

Comment: Yes I have. Checked it again as you requested. And anyway I want to set a dynamic index with the file name being included in the index which I thought of doing once this is fixed.

Comment: Also note that kibana caches the field mapping, so new fields don't always show up.  Go to Settings->Indices, select your index, and click the orange "reload" button.

Comment: Yes now it shows the data but still not all. Only 8 of it.

Comment: it appears from your kopf output that you have 4002 documents in your logstash-2015.03.06 index, so the documents appear to be loading.  Can you provide a screenshot of kibana covering that day?  Also what's in your kibana.yml file for your ES server?

Comment: Got it clarified. Thought the default index for logstash takes the timestamp as the time of parsing when indexing. But it takes the timestamp from the log file. When I set the time span to cover the date mentioned in the log file (i.e an year) it showed the logs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Several things here...

- You only have a `grok{}` in your `access` file code path
- You are getting _grokparsefailures, so your `grok { match => ["path", "G:/logstash-1.5.0/bin/tmp/(?<project>[^/_logs]+)/"] }` block isn't matching.
- You are probably running into the situation where the files are being stored into the sincedb for logstash, so you are only seeing new records in the files after you run it the first time.  You need to locate and remove your .sincedb or point it to something like /dev/null

Comment: I totally removed and reinstalled logstash and removed the "grok { match => ["path", "G:/logstash-1.5.0/bin/tmp/(?<project>[^/_logs]+)/"] }". Then I parsed the file and all the logs are being parsed and this time with no grokparsefailure. Still it shows only 8 logs. Is a limit set by default anywhere in ELK Stack?

Comment: Update your question with your current configuration and a sample of the log file (specifically lines that are not being loaded).

Comment: Updated the question with my new workings. Please refer to it.